# "Daber Davar" and appeals / auctions

Tags: shabbat, synagogue, business

As I understand, the verse in Yeshayahu ([58:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.58.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) states that one must refrain from *Daber Davr* on Shabbat, from which we learn the halacha that one should not discuss monetary matters on Shabbat ([Shabbat 113a-b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.113a.14-113b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

With that in mind, why are shuls allowed to have appeals and aliyah auctions and requests for a verbal monetary pledge from the *oleh* on Shabbat? Isn't this *Daber Davr*?

What are the criteria / restrictions on this halacha? Can the shul have **any type** of auction or appeal on Shabbat?